# why javasript cant find the variable?

Tags: javascript

```
const birthYear = 2002;
let century;
if (birthYear <= 2000) 
    let century = 20;
} else {
    let century = 21;
}
console.log(century);
```

So the problem is when i run the code console says "undefined". I wanna know what is the problem.
(I'm new at coding and all this stuff, so, please help. Thanks in advance)

Comment: Each one of those variables is a different block scoped variabled. That's how `let` works

Comment: Also see [What's the difference between using “let” and “var”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Comment: what can i do to print 21 in console log

Comment: @AnarNuruzade declare `let century` outside the `if`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

here answer

```js
const birthYear = 2002;
let century;
if (birthYear <= 2000) {

   century = 20
} else {
    century = 21
}
console.log(century)
```